# Значение переменной из другого файла

Tags: python

Есть скрипт в который получаю данные из json , парсю его получаю переменную  airport = "MRW" , есть другой файл в котором хранится что MRW="аэропорт  минеральные воды"
Как сделать чтоб при выводе print (airport) выводилось : Аэропорт минеральные воды .
Сильно не ругайтесь только начал учить питон.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как я понял, во втором файле простая структура вида (КЛЮЧ=ЗНАЧЕНИЕ)? Если так, то этот способ точно вам поможет.

Можно написать парсер для таких файлов, который будет возвращать словарь значений:

```py
# функция разбора файла
def parse(str):
    # создаём пустой словарь
    res = {}
    # разбиваем весь текст на строки
    for s in str.split('\n'):
        # их в свою очередь на две подстроки
        tmp = s.split('=', 1)
        # если в строке нет "=", то пропускаем её
        if len(tmp) == 1: continue
        # тут [0] -- это строка значение до "="
        # а [1] -- после него
        # добавляем в словарь запись вида "ключ"="значение"
        res[tmp[0]] = tmp[1]
    return res
```

Далее читаем данные из файла (для примера создам строку):

```py
str = '''
MRV=Минеральные Воды
MQF=Магнитогорск
KRO=Курган
'''
```

После парсинга можно пользоваться полученными данными как угодно:

```py
data = parse(str)
airport = 'MRV'
print(data[airport])
print(data)
```

Результат выполнения:

```
Минеральные Воды
{'MRV': 'Минеральные Воды', 'MQF': 'Магнитогорск', 'KRO': 'Курган'}
```

Comment: *Пока писал код для этого ответа, посмотрел на список названий аэропортов, в нём правильно пишется MRV...*